# Populate Combobox in winforms (C#) from a range of column header in the dataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, datagridview

im sort of stuck on how to populate a combobox with a range of headers in the dataGridView? as not all the column headers are what i want to be listed in it.
As from the code below i am displaying the data in dataGridView from an Excel file. I  would appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace GBstock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // populate the dataGridView with the Excel File //
        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", @"FilePath");
        string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet1");
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this : 
Edit : if you want to list from col3 to end for example :

```
for(i = 2; i < dgv1.Columns.Count) 
{
    cb.Items.Add(dgv1.Columns(i).HeaderText);
}
```

But why fill your combobox based on the DGV when you can fill your Combobox based on some other datasource (excel for example ?)

Comment: Thank you for this, however this lists all the headers, how would i get it to list all the columns headers from Column3 till then end? Also your comment has got me thiking maybe it would be better if i could display them from the actual excel file itself, how would i go about this? once again thank you....

Comment: I edited the post. If you want to fill it from excel, i dont really know, never worked with the Excel automation (the .Net way to access Excel files). I imagine you would have to look for the headers in the Excel file. The column header can either be identified by their property, or by their position

Comment: Thanks, ive now decided to get the columns for the combobox from the excel file, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.